# RestTemplate JSON Deserialization

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

so let's assume that we have two systems (system A and system B) that exchange information in JSON, however, the guys from System B do not want to be really cooperative and claim that everything with their payload is fine because it is "syntactically" correct JSON.

Now let's assume that you have the following json structure

```
   {
    "INFO": {
        "Animal": {
            "Cat": {}
        }
    }
   }
```

This is really a valid JSON, but the thing is you can have one or more animals, so in the scenario of more animals the payload is:

```
   {
    "INFO": {
        "Animal": [{
            "Cat": {},
"Dog" :{}
        }]
    }
   }
```

Only this time as you can see the Animal object is actually an array of objects...so System A uses RestTemplate to parse the response and has problems since the "syntactically" correct JSON differs in structure each time. Moreover, ERRORS might occur in the JSON as well - in case of errors the JSON looks like : `"ERRORS" : {[error1, error2, etc.]},`

but in case of no errors it comes as

```
"ERRORS" : ""
```

So tell me please, am I wrong for wanting the payload to be consistent and get like always an array of objects, no matter one or many, and getting no errors node in case of no errors, or am I missing something?

I'm using RestTemplate and

when the payload comes with one Animal (my pojo expects 1 or many) -> it fails as it cannot parse a single object into array list.

if I change it to expect only one Animal - it fails when more than one comes.

More than that - the "ERRORS" : "" is treated as a String which again causes parses issues.

So is there some "hack" way to make the Jackson deserializer in RestTemplate to handle this "syntactically" correct JSON, or the overall structure of the JSON should be clarified and consistent (my opinion)

Thanks!

Comment: You unfortunately have JSON that does not have a consistently defined structure, and your best option will probably be to use a `Map` and manually inspect the contents.

Comment: @chrylis, yeah but the map is really bad looking when parsed and the logic in java is awful :) but thanks for clarifying my opinion that the structure is not consistently defined!

Comment: Unfortunately, that's unavoidable if you can't provide a class "template" to map onto.

Comment: different json schemas from different systems? or both systems return both inconsistent json types based on data?

Comment: @Deadpool, System A is the consumer system which gets them inconsistent json from System B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to enable [`DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) in your `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
```

Comment: That seems like a good solution for a badly formatted json, might stick to it. Thanks! :)